# Error in NSIS script in java

Tags: java, nsis

I have installed [NSIS](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/help/eclipsensis/installation.html) plugin in my eclipse. I have followed the steps from this [site](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/help/index.html). Once I run the NSIS script, I get the following error:

```
File "..\src\main\sample\test.java"-> no files found.    
Error in script "C:\\Documents and Settings\\workspace\\setup.nsi" on line 47 -- aborting creation process
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In error is everything told. I don't understand how I can help you.

Comment: @PLB Thanks.I have test.java file in that path.but it returns error only.I dont understand why this error raised?.

Comment: Does the file `C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\src\main\sample\test.java` exists ?

Comment: @seki yes.I have file in that place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File "test.java"
```

if i remove absolute path then it works fine.so we will give only the file name that should present in your project.